# JwtToken - claim name JwtTokenTypes.Subject resolved to ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, why is that and how to prevent?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I have JwtToken created like this:

```
        X509Certificate2 cert = certificateStore.Certificate;

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, upn),
                    new Claim(REQUEST_TYPE_NAME, requestType),
                    new Claim(DOMAIN_NAME, domain),
                }),
            Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, now.AddMinutes(60)),
            SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(cert),
            TokenIssuerName = ISSUER
        };

        SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
```

This is correct. Token is created and its first claim is named "sub" which is content of JwtTokenTypes.Subject. I checked it through [jwt web](https://jwt.io/).

Problem is, I have this method for resolving claims:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)) throw new MissingTokenException("Token should not be null.");

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = new X509SecurityToken(new X509Certificate2(new X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(certificateStore.Certificate).GetX509RawData()));
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            IssuerSigningToken = securityToken,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidIssuer = ISSUER
        };

        SecurityToken securedToken = new JwtSecurityToken();
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securedToken);

        Claim claim = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(m => string.Equals(m.Type, REQUEST_TYPE_NAME, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (claim != null && !string.Equals(claim.Value, requestType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new MismatchedTokenException("Token is not of the proper type.");
        }

        upn = claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type.Equals(JwtClaimTypes.Subject) || m.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))?.Value;

        domain = claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type.Equals(DOMAIN_NAME))?.Value;
```

In the end of the method you can see I check claim name for JwtClaimTypes.Subject, which it should be, and for ClaimTypes.NameIdentifiew, which it actually is.

Do you have any idea why this transformations occur or how to prevent them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add before:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

that clears the mapping of claims for jwt.

The mapping is done to adapt the jwt claims to .net types of claims.
If you avoid the mapping you need to set the claim types for name and role if you want to use that from the Identity (IPrincipal.IsInRole or Identity.Name).

You can do this when creating the ClaimsIdentity:

```
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, upn),
            new Claim(REQUEST_TYPE_NAME, requestType),
            new Claim(DOMAIN_NAME, domain),
        }, "<auth type>", "name", "role"),
```

you'll have to change the authType to something like cookie, and the name and role claim name most probably would be like that.

The other way is to set it on the token validation parameter:

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        IssuerSigningToken = securityToken,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateActor = false,
        ValidIssuer = ISSUER,
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
```